# Разделение SQL кода и кода на основном языке через файлы

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Я понимаю, что можно

1. Держать SQL код в виде строки
2. Можно залить код в файл и читать его оттуда

Однако содержание кода в строке мне кажется не слишком элегантным решением, так как нет никакой подсветки синтаксиса, а чтение из файла не работает как хотелось бы, дает возможность получить только корневую папку, а нужно читать файл находящийся в этой же директории вместе с файлом, который пытается читать этот файл, я говорю о C#, в php было с этим проще. Вот [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653921/get-current-folder-path) не помогло. Я могу испортить структуру папок и тогда все заработает, но это мне не кажется элегантным решением

UPD: У меня есть огромный запрос на создание отсутствующих таблиц, если держать его как строковую константу нужно экранировать очень много кавычек, можно [ознакомиться](https://pastebin.com/s9MSeVca). Однако это та самая ситуация, когда скорее всего есть правильное удобное решение. Можете предлагать провайдеров БД SQL, NO-SQL, библиотеки и иное позволяющее это удобно делать

Comment: зачем тебе сырой SQL если у тебя есть Linq?

Comment: Да, держать sql-запросы в файлах нормально. "Я могу испортить структуру папок" - зачем вы портите? Делайте правильно и всё будет работать. PS: можно хранить всё это дело в ресурсах.

Comment: Какую базу данных используете? Если у вас установлен EntityFramework, то это вам здорово поможет в управлении данными в БД - не нужно запариваться с sql запросами и тд. А вообще, ваш способ, конечно, возможен, но нужен ли? Неужто нельзя заранее написать в коде нужные строки и использовать их (а-ля `const string firstSql = "SELECT ..."`). Опишите чуть подробнее, чем вы занимаетесь. Возможно, то, что вы хотите сделать, можно реализовать гораздо проще

Comment: @Grundy так работаю с базой данных, с LINQ to SQL плохо подружился, оно же только с SQL Server? Поэтому с sqlite вроде бы не сработает, не разбирался возможно ли это.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov держать в ресурсах? Гуглить "Хранение ресурсов в сборке"?

Comment: @Frehzy БД sqlite, так заранее нужные строки подготавливать значит использовать параметры для ADO.NET типа IDataParameter, я попробовал попользоваться и не понял почему вместо них не использовать строковую интерполяцию

Comment: Пробывали [хранимые процедуры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0)?

Comment: `... параметры ... почему вместо них не использовать строковую интерполяцию` - Джун не использовал параметры, в результате чего хакеры дропнули базу данных. Что с ним сделали? Ищите на порносайтах в разделе Жесть.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru почитал, сейчас попробую, можно оформлять как ответ

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov поорал и понял, но в ado.net интерфейсах мне показалось очень неудобный интерфейс для создания параметров для команд, код растягивается. Да и тут проект без требований к безопасности, так как приложение для локалки, но знать надо конечно. Тоже как ответ пойдет

Comment: _оно же только с SQL Server?_ - нет, какой провайдер подключишь - такой и будет

Answer (score 0):

Нашел одно из решений - хранить sql код в файлах ресурсов.

Создать файл ресурсов как говорят [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/7k989cfy(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Использовать файлы в коде как говорят [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964942/how-to-access-resource-file-in-c)